# Typescript react children with type specified in function directly instead of using an interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Why does this work:

```
interface UserSidebarProps {
  children? : React.ReactNode
}

function UserSidebar({children}: UserSidebarProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But this does not

```
function UserSidebar(children?: React.ReactNode) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
// Usage
<UserSidebar>hello world</UserSidebar>
```

When trying to use it, the second option gives an error in vscode of:

```
Type '{ children: Element | null; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ReactNode'.
  Type '{ children: Element | null; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, type, props
```

I would have thought these two definitions are completely equivalent, how are they different and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, regardless of any Typescript, your signatures do not match. `UserSidebar({children})` vs `UserSidebar(children)`. Fix that first, then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that when creating a component, the props definition (the parameter of your function) should be of a class where its properties represents the props of your component. Practically, this means that on the second example you should do something like:

```
function UserSidebar({children}: {children?: React.ReactNode}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
   )
}
```

Or you could use the PropsWithChildren class like this:

```
function UserSidebar({children}: PropsWithChildren) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not using an interface or not, the problem is that you changed the signature of the function (the arguments it accepts). If I remove the Typescript, can you see the difference?

```
function UserSidebar({children}) {

function UserSidebar(children) {
```

React passes props to components, and you have said that your component DOES NOT accept props, only a `ReactNode`.

Try adding the brace brackets again.

```
function UserSidebar({children}: {children: React.ReactNode;}) {
```

Comment: Your solution did not work with the error: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'ReactNode'

Comment: @sev yes, my mistake, sorry! I've fixed it.